# Subsetting Panel Data in R

Tags: r, subset, panel-data

I am trying to subset a panel dataset to read only the first 855 observations for each "Region". The region column has 65 different regions and each region has 1070 observations. From this, I want to reduce the dataset to have all the 65 regions but only their first 855 observations (reducing every other variable accordingly).

```
     Region       Week       VolSales  UnitSales BaseVol  BaseUnits 
1065 Los Angeles 02/01/2011    2004.80  2166.18   1921.53  1934.84         
1066 Los Angeles 02/01/2011    1949.03  1479.03   1700.07  1700.07           
1067 Los Angeles 02/01/2011    5231.11  5904.96   4846.51  4811.38           
1068 Los Angeles 02/01/2011    6267.45  6524.85   4675.77  4328.05           
1069 Los Angeles 02/01/2011    2317.29  2180.61   1795.83  1019.11           
1070 Los Angeles 02/01/2011    3433.70  3493.10   1729.77  2179.09
```

The closest I could get was to define data for each region with a new variable and then subsetting it, something like this:

```
R1 <- subset(data, data$Region == "Los Angeles")
R2 <- subset(data, data$Region == "Chicago")
```

and so on....
and then taking

```
Sample1 <- R1[1:855]
Sample2 <- R2[1:855]
```

and then combining it to form the whole dataset and arranging back according to Regions (as arranged in the original dataset)

`FinalDataset <- cbind(Sample1,Sample2`)

But ofcourse, this is not an efficient way and I am looking forward to get some help doing it more efficiently. I hope I explained the question correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using base R:

```
List = by(data, data$Region, function(x) x[1:855,])

FinalDataset = do.call('rbind', List)
```

If you want to use the data.table package:

```
data = data.table(data)
FinalDataset = data[,.SD[1:855],by=Region]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 data %>% 
 group_by(Region) %>% 
 do(head(., n=855))
```

#### Example

```
 set.seed(24)
 data <- data.frame(Region=rep(c("Los Angeles", "Chicago"),each=10), Value=rnorm(20),stringsAsFactors=F)

 data%>% group_by(Region) %>% do(head(., n=2))
 #Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
  #Groups: Region
  #
  #       Region      Value
 #1      Chicago -1.3169081
 #2      Chicago  0.5982691
 #3  Los Angeles -0.5458808
 #4  Los Angeles  0.5365853
```